# Can JaCoCo be configured to show how many tests cover each line of code?

Tags: tdd, code-coverage, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, istanbul

Can I configure JaCoCo to output how many tests cover each line of code (Just like how Istanbul code coverage works with Karma test runner)

Istanbul + Karma (JavaScript): (notice the numbers in the left margin... thats how many tests cover that line)

[image: Istanbul + Karma generated code coverage]

JaCoCo (Java):

[image: JaCoCo generated code coverage]

My Istanbul setup is Grunt, Karma (basically the Yeoman AngularJS template)

My JaCoCo setup is, well its a Android project. Its is basically this at the moment: https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template

Answer (score 1):

Jacoco don't have this kind of functionality.